# Given a string 's' of length n, calculate the number of occurrences of a character 'c' of s in all substrings of s

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, formula

Consider the string aba.

All of its substrings are: [a,b,a,ab,ba,aba].

In the above list, character 'a' appears 6 times and b appears 4 times.

Is there any formula for calculating this? that is the number of occurrences of a character 'c' of s in all substrings of s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a string of length n, there are n(n+1)/2 substrings.

The character at index i appears once in every substring, except for the substrings that end at character i-1 or before, and except for the substrings that start at character i+1 or after. Note that here I'm only counting this specific occurrence of the character at index i.

Let me rephrase that: in a string `S c T`, where `S` and `T` are two substrings and `c` is a character, this occurrence of character `c` appears once in every substring of `S c T`, except in substrings of `S` and in substrings of `T`.

Thus the number of substrings in which appears the character at index `i` in a string of length `n` is:

```
k_i = n(n+1)/2 - i(i+1)/2 - (n-i-1)(n-i)/2
```

If we expand, cancel out terms, and refactor:

```
k_i = n(n+1)/2 - i(i+1)/2 - (n-i-1)(n-i)/2
k_i = (n(n+1) - i(i+1) - (n-i-1)(n-i)) / 2
k_i = (n²+n -i²-i -n²+ni+in-i²+n-i) / 2
k_i = (2n + 2ni -2i - 2i²) / 2
k_i = n + ni - i - i²
k_i = n(i+1) - i(i+1)
k_i = (i+1) (n-i)
```

We can sum on all occurrences of this character. In python, this gives the following function:

```py
def count_occurences_in_substrings(s, c):
    n = len(s)
    return sum(
        (i + 1) * (n - i)
        for i, a in enumerate(s) if a == c
    )
```

Testing by comparing against a bruteforce function that actually generates the substrings:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def bruteforce(s, c):
    return ''.join(s[i:j] for i,j in combinations(range(len(s)+1), 2)).count(c)

for s in ['aba', 'abcdefg', 'bcdaefg']:
    k1 = count_occurences_in_substrings(s, 'a')
    k2 = bruteforce(s, 'a')
    print('{:8s}: {:2d},{:2d}'.format(s, k1, k2))
# aba     :  6, 6
# abcdefg :  7, 7
# bcdaefg : 16,16
```